# Github how to track commits only from certain users

Tags: github, gitlab

I wish to trigger an action(maybe send a mail/alert) when the code is committed only for my team members which is a very small subset of large number of contributors. Is there a way to track commits only from certain specific users in Github/Gitlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can even automate this process using a webhook. In case you aren't familiar - a webhook delivers a JSON payload when a certain event occurs.

By setting up a webhook on the GitHub [`push event`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) you'll create alerts every time a push is made to your repository. You can create a small script that scans the author value.  If the value matches one of your team members you can configure your alert/mailer, otherwise you can configure your script to ignore the webhook's payload.